# mysql search for records using string replace

Tags: mysql

Let's suppose I have a table like this...

```
id | value
----------
1  | 4
2  | a8
3  | 13
4  | a2
5  | 7
```

So some numbers in the value have an "a" in front of them and others don't.

Now let's say I wanted to pull out anything higher than 6 - including any number with an "a" in front of it.

So a query that looked something like this (inserting some PHP that I know wouldn't work in SQL)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE str_replace("a","",value)>6;
```

The expected results should be...

```
id | value
----------
2  | a8
3  | 13
5  | 7
```

Please note that I don't want to actually get rid of the "a"s in the SQL table.  The table should remain untouched.  It's okay if the result back doesn't have the "a" in it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to:

1. Clean the data
2. Cast to int (using `+ 0` as a shortcut)
3. Use the result to filter

Try this:

```
SELECT id, value FROM table
WHERE REPLACE(value, "a", "") + 0 > 6
```

If you also wanted to have the "cleaned" field in your results you would have to add the `REPLACE` into your select statement too:

```
SELECT id, REPLACE(value, "a", "") + 0 value FROM table
WHERE REPLACE(value, "a", "") + 0 > 6
```

Comment: This is it!  Thanks so much!  (will mark as answer as soon as I'm allowed)